# Adaptivecard Input.choicset field is not working in Teams channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Issue: In Adaptive card there is a dropdown element (input.choiceset) which contains our application technician list (users who are part of our application).  This list will be used to assign the ticket to one of the technicians. When we use component, it works properly in personal scope where as it doesn't work as intended when displayed in Team channel.

Note : We are sending the same adaptive card response for Messaging extension invoke call for both teams channel and personal chat scope.

I have attached the sample card JSON payload which we tried.

Sample payload:

```
{
  "content": {
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
      {
        "items": [
          {
            "color": "attention",
            "horizontalAlignment": null,
            "isSubtle": false,
            "maxLines": 0,
            "size": "large",
            "text": "#1884    without",
            "weight": "bolder",
            "wrap": true,
            "spacing": "Default",
            "separator": false,
            "type": "TextBlock"
          }
        ],
        "separator": false,
        "type": "Container"
      },
      {
        "columns": [
          {
            "width": "auto",
            "items": [
              {
                "horizontalAlignment": "right",
                "size": "small",
                "style": "person",
                "url": "https://as-prod.asyncgw.teams.microsoft.com/urlp/v1/url/content?url=https%3a%2f%2fcontacts.localzoho.com%2ffile%3fexp%3d10%26ID%3d-1%26t%3duser%26height%3d60%26width%3d60",
                "width": "35px",
                "height": "35px",
                "separator": false,
                "type": "Image"
              }
            ],
            "separator": false,
            "type": "Column"
          },
          {
            "width": "stretch",
            "items": [
              {
                "color": null,
                "horizontalAlignment": null,
                "isSubtle": false,
                "maxLines": 0,
                "size": null,
                "text": "Aa Guru Req",
                "weight": "bolder",
                "wrap": true,
                "spacing": "Default",
                "separator": false,
                "type": "TextBlock"
              },
              {
                "color": null,
                "horizontalAlignment": null,
                "isSubtle": true,
                "maxLines": 0,
                "size": "small",
                "text": "Mar 24, 2023 06:50 PM",
                "weight": "lighter",
                "wrap": true,
                "spacing": "None",
                "separator": false,
                "type": "TextBlock"
              }
            ],
            "separator": false,
            "type": "Column"
          }
        ],
        "separator": true,
        "type": "ColumnSet"
      },
      {
        "items": [
          {
            "facts": [
              {
                "title": "Status",
                "value": "Open"
              },
              {
                "title": "Technician",
                "value": "Not Assigned"
              },
              {
                "title": "Priority",
                "value": "Not Assigned"
              }
            ],
            "spacing": "Medium",
            "separator": true,
            "type": "FactSet"
          },
          {
            "color": null,
            "horizontalAlignment": null,
            "isSubtle": false,
            "maxLines": 0,
            "size": null,
            "text": "You can view in [ServiceDesk Plus Cloud](https://sdpondemand.localmanageengine.com/app/itdesk/ui/requests/4213000001845143/details)",
            "weight": null,
            "wrap": true,
            "spacing": "Medium",
            "separator": false,
            "type": "TextBlock"
          },
          {
            "color": null,
            "horizontalAlignment": null,
            "isSubtle": false,
            "maxLines": 0,
            "size": null,
            "text": " ",
            "weight": null,
            "wrap": true,
            "spacing": "Medium",
            "separator": false,
            "type": "TextBlock"
          }
        ],
        "separator": false,
        "type": "Container"
      }
    ],
    "actions": [
      {
        "card": {
          "type": "AdaptiveCard",
          "body": [
            {
              "isMultiline": true,
              "maxLength": 0,
              "placeholder": "Add Notes",
              "style": null,
              "value": "",
              "isRequired": false,
              "id": "addnote",
              "separator": false,
              "type": "Input.Text"
            }
          ],
          "actions": [
            {
              "data": {
                "mode": "add notes",
                "msteams": {
                  "text": "cardAction add notes",
                  "type": "messageBack"
                },
                "requestId": "4213000001845143",
                "portalId": "63097041",
                "displayId": "1884"
              },
              "title": "Save",
              "type": "Action.Submit"
            }
          ],
          "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
          "version": "1.2"
        },
        "title": "Add Notes",
        "type": "Action.ShowCard"
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "mode": "pickup",
          "msteams": {
            "text": "cardAction pickup",
            "type": "messageBack"
          },
          "requestId": "4213000001845143",
          "portalId": "63097041",
          "displayId": "1884"
        },
        "title": "Pick up",
        "type": "Action.Submit"
      },
      {
        "card": {
          "type": "AdaptiveCard",
          "body": [
            {
              "choices": [
                {
                  "title": "Chennai",
                  "value": "4213000000207015"
                },
                {
                  "title": "qamailtest",
                  "value": "4213000000650033"
                },
                {
                  "title": "Santhosh",
                  "value": "4213000001226072"
                }
              ],
              "isMultiSelect": false,
              "style": null,
              "placeholder": "Assign To",
              "isRequired": false,
              "id": "assignTO",
              "separator": false,
              "type": "Input.ChoiceSet"
            }
          ],
          "actions": [
            {
              "data": {
                "mode": "assign to",
                "msteams": {
                  "text": "cardAction assign to",
                  "type": "messageBack"
                },
                "requestId": "4213000001845143",
                "portalId": "63097041",
                "displayId": "1884"
              },
              "title": "Assign",
              "type": "Action.Submit"
            }
          ],
          "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
          "version": "1.2"
        },
        "title": "Assign To",
        "type": "Action.ShowCard"
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "mode": "close",
          "msteams": {
            "text": "cardAction close",
            "type": "messageBack"
          },
          "requestId": "4213000001845143",
          "portalId": "63097041",
          "displayId": "1884"
        },
        "title": "close",
        "type": "Action.Submit"
      }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2"
  },
  "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
  "preview": {
    "content": {
      "title": "#1884    without",
      "text": "Open | Not Assigned | Mar 24, 2023 06:50 PM"
    },
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail"
  }
}
```

Attached the screenshots for your reference:

(i) Assign To field (Input.choiceSet field in adaptive card) in personal chat (Dropdown listed and Working)
[image]

(ii)Assign To field (Input.choiceSet field in adaptive card) in Teams channel chat (Dropdown not listed)
[image]

Comment: We are also able to repro this issue, we have raised a bug for the same. We will keep you posted on the updates. Thanks!

Comment: We checked this at our end, and it is working fine, could you please check at your end once? It is working fine in new Teams T2.1 as well - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJKiq.png
We checked in Microsoft Teams Desktop (Version 1.6.00.23458) and web client.